# How to log into multiple accounts in Hotot 0.9.8.10

Tags: twitter, hotot

I am using Hotot 0.9.8.10 and am un-able to figure out how to log into multiple accounts.

I know it is possible, because I have heard people talking about it, but I can not seem to figure it out.

Comment: The developer has stopped developing it.Many bugs are there and still not having any kind of solution.you'd better go for any other alternative.

Comment: People really need to stop making assumptions like this. The day after putting out the bounty, he tweeted that he was working on Multiple Acccount Support.

Answer (score 0):

On the sign in page, barely visible, there is a plus sign right below the hotot logo. Click it.

Took me a while to find it.

Comment: Could you upload a screenshoot? Remember that you can upload it in imgur.com and then link it here.

Answer (score -1):

You need to logout and click to plus, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBhCJ.jpg) is a screen shot:

[image: screenshot of Hotot showing faded plus sign at upper-left corner]